# Question format using did

Tags: questions, past-simple, do-support

Is there any meaning difference in below questions?

a) Which movie you saw yesterday?

b) Which movie did you see yesterday?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a different between your two sentences. The difference is that the first sentence is not grammatical (it's simply wrong). Only the second one is grammatical. In English, when you're asking a question that begins with a question word (those are words like *why*, *when*, *what*, *where* etc.), the subject of the sentence must be preceded by something called [**a helping verb**](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/auxiliary.htm) (those are words like *do*, *does*, *did*, *have* etc.) unless the main verb is a form of the verb *to be* in which case the verb itself gets moved to the front. Here's the pattern to follow:

> [**question word**] [**helping verb**] subject [**main verb**]?

Examples:

> **What** movie **did** you **watch** yesterday?
>
> **Where** **were** you last night?

Note that it's just not possible to ignore this rule in situations when a sentence begins with a question word as in our case here, but when it doesn't, all bets are off and all that was mentioned above does not necessarily hold true. For instance:

> **Did** you **make** it for me?
>
> You **made** it for me?

I think the last example is the source of your confusion. You heard people say it like that and thought that a helping verb can be optional. I don't want to sound like a broken record, but when a sentence begins with a question word, a helping verb in front of the subject is not optional. So, *which movie you saw yesterday* is very bad grammar. However, you don't need it when the question word occurs in the middle of the sentence: *You saw what movie yesterday?* That's a perfectly valid sentence.